How to handle memory issue in Heroku?
I went through this article https://help.heroku.com/TWBM7DL0/how-do-i-measure-current-memory-use-and-max-available-memory-on-a-dyno-in-a-private-space
to learn about How do I measure current memory use and max available memory on a dyno in a Private Space?. But the problem is in Heroku, this file does not exist /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes so, I cannot retrieve the value of current memory usuage of the dynos. But this file exist /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes. I am getting this information in my log and that dynos get timed out.
Process running mem=2062(200.3%)
Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)
Stopping process with SIGKILL
State changed from up to complete
Process exited with status 137

So, I was wondering is there a way to track the memory usage of the dynos and if percentage get greater than 60-70% than kill the process and start new process.
